# try to add two columns in pandas data frame, always get error

Tags: python, pandas

please see code and return
new to Python and really appreciate your help!

```
df['Height'] = df['Wall Top'] - df['Elevation']
```

[image: return error]

Comment: Looks like you're trying to subtract floats from strings.

Comment: provide rest of the code we can tell you where things got messy

Answer (score 2):

The columns of your df are of different types. if you type:

```
df.dtypes
```

You'll see that one is str and one is float, or both are object type. You need to do this:

```
df['Height'] = df['Wall Top'].astype(float) - df['Elevation'].astype(float)
```

It should do the calculation you want.

Answer (score -1):

If you read the error, seems like a data type issue

```
df['Height'] = df['Wall Top'].astype(float) - df['Elevation'].astype(float)
```

or you can following existing [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/pandas-change-data-type-of-columns?rq=1)

Comment: you just changed your solution to mine...not cool